# Lookup an unassigned CSS class style using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Does jQuery provide a way to lookup a style defined in a CSS class without first assigning that class to an element?

e.g. given the following CSS I would like to retrieve the Color style assigned to myClass -

```
.myClass {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

So far the only way I've found is to temporarily assign the class to an element and then interrogate the element, but I get inconsistant results between different browsers.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Check out jQuery.rule (http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/11/jqueryrule.html), sounds like what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out and post my results.